# A long operation of org.eclipse.core.expressions.PropertyTester makes UI not responsive

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I try to monitor the `activeEditor` and once the activeEditor changes, one property tester will performed to test some conditions.

I need to implement some operations involving networking and IO in `public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args, Object expectedValue)` of PropertyTester.

However, this implement will make UI not responsive so I would like to move this operation outside UI thread. However, I don't know how to pass the result back to UI thread. Does RCP has any existing mechanism to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The UI thread is stalled while it waits for a property tester to complete so there is no way to do this. Property testers must be fast.